# ggplot log scale axis tick value as 10 fold increase between interval dynamically from data

Tags: r, ggplot2

log scale 10 fold interval between ticks automatically setting minimum and maximum from data.

tried with lseq(1,2000,5) but it did not give desired result. I want  as 1,10,100,1000,10000. But min,max dynanamically selected from data. but min,max needs to be adjusted to nearest lower end 1 or 0.1  or 0.01 of input data point.ex: 1 means 1, 0.5 means 0.1. Max is nearest higher end of data.ex:1300 means 10000. so scale always like 0.01,0.1,1,10,100,1000,10000 etc.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(emdbook)

df= data.frame(x=c(0,7,14,21,28,35,42,49),y=c(20,208,153,256,401,613,807,1300))

p= ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) +geom_line() + geom_point()

p <<- p+scale_y_log10(breaks = lseq(1,2000,5),
                       labels=lseq(1,2000,5),limits=c(1,2000))

p
```

got as 1,6.68,44,299,2000. expect as 1,10,100,1000,10000 .

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I like to use the function `comma` from package `scales` for the labels. If you move into decimals, this labeling won't work. I commented out a line that may look better.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

df <- data.frame(x = c(0,7,14,21,28,35,42,49),
                 y = c(20,208,153,256,401,613,807,1300))

y_lims <- 10^c(min(floor(min(log10(df$y))), 0), ceiling(max(log10(df$y))))

p <- ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
p <- p + scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                       labels = comma,
                       #labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)),
                       limits = y_lims)

p
```

Comment: Thanks, it starts from 10.  i want to have like  1,10,100,1000,10000. moreover  min 1 and max 10000 should come from data. EXample if have data min=3, max =1400, then i should get break selected for axis as  1, 10,100,1000,  10000. trying a lot dynamically. could not achieve. is there any function to get break like this ?

Comment: It was starting from 1 for me. But here is an update. Only thing I didn't add in was smooth number formatting for when the scale hits decimals. Will have to play around with what you like there.

Comment: thanks. beautifully worked. sometime I need Y axis starting in decimals like 0.01,0.1,1,10  100 1000 10000 etc.. I will try.